# Mapping values of one array onto another

Tags: python, arrays

Let's say I have an array of x values in Python

`[1 2 3 4 5]`

and a corresponding array of y value data

`[10 11 6 2.5 0]`

Now let's say I want to restrict the domain of x to

`[2 3 4]`

How do I produce the corresponding y-array?

`[11 6 2.5]`

Comment: How are you generating the restricted list? If you have the indexes, it's trivial (just apply them to both lists)

Comment: Use array of tuples or a dictionary.

Comment: @xjcl good question. I have the indexes, but how do I restrict either of the list to those indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `start_index` and `end_index` set:

```
x_restricted = x_values[start_index:end_index]
y_restricted = y_values[start_index:end_index]
```

Note Python uses half-open intervals, meaning the element at `end_index` itself is excluded.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> y = [10, 11, 6, 2.5, 0]
>>> x_filtered = [2, 3, 4]
>>> [ey for ex, ey in zip(x, y) if ex in x_filtered]
[11, 6, 2.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index method of the `list`.

But note, this would assume x has unique integers and both the values are present in x.

```
y[x.index(2):x.index(5)+1]
```